# Searching through directory with recursive function for txt files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a function that has a chosen folder and looks through for all files that are .txt extension.

The problem is that it will only search through and looks through the folders inside the chosen folder. It WON'T look at the .txt files that are in the chosen folders top layer, just the files in the sub-directories:

Chosen_Folder

---

test1.txt
 test2.txt
 Folder1
 Folder2

So in other words, it ignores test1.txt, test2.txt, it will however find all .txt files in the folder and those folders sub-directories as well.

Here is my code:

```
public static void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {




        string ExtractedTXTBlocks = FINAL_PATH + "\\" + "Extracted TXT Blocks";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ExtractedTXTBlocks);

        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {
                    string[] filelines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
                    string line = "";
                    string sBuilder = "";
                    int i = 1;
                    string temp = "";

                    string Fname = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("\\"), (f.Length - f.LastIndexOf("\\"))).Replace("\\","");
                    string Dname = d.Substring(d.LastIndexOf("\\"), (d.Length - d.LastIndexOf("\\"))).Replace("\\","");
                    StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(ExtractedTXTBlocks, Dname +"-" +Fname), true);


                    foreach (string item in filelines)
                    {
                        i++;
                        line = item;


                        line = (line.Replace("CMD", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("0x", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("0X", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("DI", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("SW", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LO 0", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LI", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LE 0", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("REM", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("$", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LO", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("DO", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace(" ", "")).Trim();

                        if (line.StartsWith("1234") || line.StartsWith("1233"))
                        {

                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8);
                            int number = int.Parse(temp);
                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8).Replace(line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8), number.ToString("x").ToUpper());
                            line = line.Remove(8, line.Length - 8);
                            line += temp;
                            sBuilder = line;


                        }
                        else if (line.StartsWith("1235") || line.StartsWith("1255"))
                        {

                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8);
                            int number = int.Parse(temp);                                
                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8).Replace(line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8),number.ToString("x").ToUpper());
                            line = line.Remove(8, line.Length - 8);
                            line += temp;
                            sBuilder = line;


                        }

                        else if (line.Equals("Success"))
                        {

                            sW.WriteLine(sBuilder);                                
                            sBuilder = "";

                        }                            
                        else
                        {
                            if (!line.Equals(""))
                            {
                                sBuilder += line;
                            }


                        }





                    }
                    sW.Close();



                }
                DirSearch(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried maybe setting the SearchOption to AllDirectories in the get folder method Directory.GetDirectories, but I think this is not what I need to do. I fear I am missing something very small.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
 Directory.GetFiles(d,"*.txt")
```

Comment: This does not work either. That only sees all files through the current "d" folder. Again the files on the top layer are ignored.

Comment: I don't see the difference in that the directory is still "d". I tried this and it still does not find all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but I found another option here:

```
public static void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {




        string ExtractedTXTBlocks = FINAL_PATH + "\\" + "Extracted TXT Blocks";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ExtractedTXTBlocks);

        try
        {

                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.TXT", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    string[] filelines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
                    string line = "";
                    string sBuilder = "";
                    int i = 1;
                    string temp = "";

                    string Fname = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("\\"), (f.Length - f.LastIndexOf("\\"))).Replace("\\","");
                    string Dname = Path.GetDirectoryName(f);
                    Dname = Dname.Substring(Dname.LastIndexOf("\\"), Dname.Length - Dname.LastIndexOf("\\")).Replace("\\", "");

                    StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(ExtractedTXTBlocks + "\\" + Dname + "-" + Fname, true);

                    foreach (string item in filelines)
                    {
                        i++;
                        line = item;


                        line = (line.Replace("CMD", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("0x", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("0X", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("DI", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("SW", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LO 0", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LI", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LE 0", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("REM", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("$", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("LO", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace("DO", "")).Trim();
                        line = (line.Replace(" ", "")).Trim();

                        if (line.StartsWith("1234") || line.StartsWith("1233"))
                        {

                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8);
                            int number = int.Parse(temp);
                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8).Replace(line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8), number.ToString("x").ToUpper());
                            line = line.Remove(8, line.Length - 8);
                            line += temp;
                            sBuilder = line;


                        }
                        else if (line.StartsWith("1235") || line.StartsWith("1255"))
                        {

                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8);
                            int number = int.Parse(temp);                                
                            temp = line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8).Replace(line.Substring(8, line.Length - 8),number.ToString("x").ToUpper());
                            line = line.Remove(8, line.Length - 8);
                            line += temp;
                            sBuilder = line;


                        }

                        else if (line.Equals("Success"))
                        {

                            sW.WriteLine(sBuilder);                                
                            sBuilder = "";

                        }                            
                        else
                        {
                            if (!line.Equals(""))
                            {
                                sBuilder += line;
                            }


                        }





                    }
                    sW.Close();



                }

        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

This will just go through all files in the folder I say to look in, including the sub directories. I wanted to use the recursion scheme however it was not to well optimized for what I wanted to do.

Kind Regards.